# htaccess 301 redirection to a folder without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my website to a folder

```
Example
from: www.mysite.com
to: www.mysite.com/foldername
Final URL after redirection: same as from
```

My htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.ru\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ foldername [L]
```

I don't want to show the foldername after the redirection. 
How to rewrite it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: what i meant by that is i want to redirect the url to a folder. My core files are in a sub folder called "en" instead of seeing www.mywebsite.com/en when i redirect, i want to hide the folder "en".

Comment: In that case starkeen's answer should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mod-rewrite** .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !foldername /foldername%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will internally redirect your site from **/** to **/foldername** .

Comment: Hi starken, i update my question above, i inserted the redirection code. i tried your suggestion but still the foldername is showing